# exec() won't play (php on Apache)

Tags: php, apache, shell

My exec() command stopped working. I am calling exec() from a PHP script on a Dreamhost Apache server.

Below is a test-script:

```
$disabled = explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions'));
if (in_array('exec', $disabled)) 
    echo 'exec is in array of disabled functions';
else
    echo 'exec is NOT in array of disabled functions';
echo '</br> exec(ls): </br>';
$command = 'ls';
exec($command,$output,$returnvar);
echo '</br> output is: </br>';
var_dump($output);
echo '</br> return var is: </br>';
var_dump($returnvar);
```

The output is:

```
exec is NOT in array of disabled functions
exec(ls):

output is:

array
  empty


return var is:

int 1
```

IMHO, this tells me that exec() is enabled on my system. $return_var is set to 1, and Google assures me that this indicates 'minor problems'.

What could be the issue here? Why won't exec() work?

Comment: add this on top of your script: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: I would say it's a rights issue (command not found is usually 127 in my experience). Can you `stat("/bin/ls");`? Look at the mode, uid, gid, and your current user/group id.

Comment: try `if(function_exists('exec')) {echo "exec is enabled";}`

Comment: **error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);** does not make a difference

Comment: **stat("/bin/ls");** fails. Apparently this is not the location of the ls command on my system. By the way **stat('/usr/local/php53/bin/php/ls');** fails just the same

Comment: **if(function_exists('exec')** returns **exec is enabled**

Answer (score 0):

More then likely it is a path issue, try using an absolute path

> $command = '/path/to/ls'; //i think its /bin/ls

If the command isnt found you usually get empty results ( you have to capture the error output a different way )

Comment: No luck. I tried both **/bin/ls** and **/usr/local/php53/bin/php/ls** (which I got off of Dreamhost's Wiki). Both have the same result: empty array and result_var = 1.

Answer (score 0):

This could be either a path problem or the app cannot access command you are trying to access.

Add `2>&1` to the end of your exec command and see what the output is.  More than likely this will allow you to see what is stopping the command from executing.  `2>&1` tells the OS to send the STDERR to STDOUT.

For example instead of

```
exec('ls');
```

Try

```
exec('ls 2>&1');
```